# How to disable automatic schema registration in Apache Flink's Avro serializer?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, avro, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

Using the Avro serializers provided by the Confluent platform, it is possible to disable schema registration during serialization. I.e., when a schema is not already registered as a schema version for a subject, an exception is raised (by default, the subject is generated and the schema is registered for this subject). This is useful when you don't want to leave schema registration to the producers to a Kafka topic.

I do not see the same option in the `ConfluentRegistryAvroSerializationSchema` provided by `flink-formats` for Apache Flink, i.e., it seems that the Avro serialization in Apache Flink always attempts to register the schema and create the corresponding subject. Is there a way to avoid this?